# Unable to parse string into int is causing my program to crash, and other errors?

Tags: android, xml

I've got the main java file here: 
http://pastebin.com/S76bgi7a

The XML file here:
http://pastebin.com/8CJj0S54

And a pastebin ID for my strings here:
2sk1emgB

Short version: I run my program, it crashes, i'm not sure why.  I look in the logcat and it gives me

04-27 02:58:47.927: E/AndroidRuntime(394): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{walmart.namespace/walmart.namespace.WalmartActivity}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse 'Please enter a department name' as integer.

I can't figure out where in my text it's trying to convert a string into a number, aside from the case/ifthen statements.  I apologize if my code is noobish, i am a novice at it.

Edit:  Same problem, only now i'm getting a

04-27 03:19:08.858: E/AndroidRuntime(448): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{walmart.namespace/walmart.namespace.WalmartActivity}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse '' as integer.

I'm guessing this comes from my OnClickListener for it, which is supposed to delete the string when clicked.

Comment: Learn the basics of java and you can actually understand why its not working. Blinding coding **DOESN'T** help anyone.

Comment: I'd love to if I didn't have a project due in a week and the teacher knows nothing about his craft.

Comment: Then learn to read what the errors mean, this will help you even more.

Comment: I'm trying to. The two single quote lines don't even show up in my code.

Answer (score 0):

The error seems pretty clear:

> unable to parse 'Please enter a department name' as integer.

That string is in your resources as `dptnum`. You use it in your XML as follows:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etNum"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="int"
    android:text="@string/dptnum" />
```

As the error says, it's expecting an integer (you set the `inputType` as `int`) and you're giving it a string. Perhaps you wanted this instead:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etNum"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="int"
    android:hint="@string/dptnum" />
```

Comment: Thanks.  Now it's giving me another error for good measure. >_<

Answer (score 0):

It's because you set text in :

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/etName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text"
            android:text="@string/dptname"  />
```

If you want to prompt user to do somethings like "enter ab yxz here ", you may want to use `"android:hint"` instead.

And secondly, use "try .... catch(NumberFormatException)"  for these case, trust me, it would save you a lot of effort when debug.

Comment: Thanks.  It's still giving me an error.  I've also never used a try/catch statement, much less how to use it.